# display.html Typescript not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have Timer function, that does countdown. I move it from js to ts code

Here is code of function (TS)

```
  export module Timer {
   export function startTimer(duration, display){
    let session_timer;
    Date.now = Date.now || (() => +new Date);
    const start = Date.now();
    let diff = 0;
    let minutes:any = 0;
    let seconds:any = 0;
    const timer = function() {
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
        if (minutes < 0) { minutes = "0"; }
        if (seconds < 0) { seconds = "0"; }
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
        display.html(`${minutes}:${seconds}`);
        if (diff <= 0) {
          $(this).changePage('#session_timer');
          return clearInterval(session_timer);
        }
      };

      timer();
      return session_timer = setInterval(timer, 1000);
   };

}


export default Timer;
```

I importing it to index.ts, webpack component like this

```
import Timer from "./scripts/timer";
```

export default Timer;

And than call in `step2.js` pack

Like this

```
 import Timer from "../components/timer";

$(document).ready(() => {
  Timer.startTimer();
});
```

But when I try to run project I have this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined

JS Code is was this

```
 window.startTimer = function(duration, display) {
    let session_timer;
    Date.now = Date.now || (() => +new Date);
    const start = Date.now();
    let diff = 0;
    let minutes = 0;
    let seconds = 0;

    const timer = function() {
      diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
      minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
      seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
      if (minutes < 0) { minutes = "0"; }
      if (seconds < 0) { seconds = "0"; }
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
      display.html(`${minutes}:${seconds}`);
      if (diff <= 0) {
        $(this).changePage('#session_timer');
        return clearInterval(session_timer);
      }
    };

    timer();
    return session_timer = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  };
```

How I can fix it? In JS all working great

Comment: You are using a `display` variable. Where is it defined? Apparently is not, and hence the error.

Comment: It's in parameters. I updated post @OscarPaz

Comment: Well, apparently, if is `undefined`. Check it with `console.log(display)` just before calling `display.html`

Comment: What type does the Typescript compiler understand `display` to be? You might have to explicitly annotate it: `display: JQuery`.

Comment: Yes, it's undefined @OscarPaz

Comment: Then you need to check where you're calling this function, and see what you are passing to it as parameters

Comment: You pass `display` into your function `export function startTimer(duration, **display**)` so where are you consuming `Timer` and how are you calling it?

Comment: I will now edit question@Liam

Comment: You are not passing anything in Timer.startTimer() function

Comment: Edit question  @Liam

Comment: `Timer.startTimer(duration,display);`  is not working too@parth

Comment: You should try passing duration as number and display as element of HTML. Then it will work. I tested in JS

Comment: How were  you calling that function before, in JavaScript?

Comment: `<%= javascript_tag "startTimer(#{@search.session_timer}, $('#time_left'))" %>`

I think like this in View@OscarPaz

Comment: `Timer.startTimer();` should be passing `duration, display`. `display` is undefined because....your not defining it... you still haven't told us what `display` is supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display` is `undefined` because you're not defining it...

You need to call your function thus:

```
import Timer from "../components/timer";


let display = ;//whatever this is supposed to be?
//e.g. let display = $('.myClass'); 
//to pass in a html element of myClass.

$(document).ready(() => {
  Timer.startTimer(100, display);
});
```

I'm presuming this is supposed to be a jQuery HTML element and that is why your calling `display.html(...)`

Comment: And also because the OP stated in a comment that the call looks like this: `startTimer(#{@search.session_timer}, $('#time_left'))`

Comment: Yup, thank's for help.I will post full answer, that describes solving of my problem

Answer (score 0):

So here is answer for my question

Since data was getting at past from View like this:

```
startTimer(#{@search.session_timer}, $('#time_left'))
```

I need function to get data from back end (from View is not working anymore).

So I make on back end variable `gon.timer`

So calling of my function in pack need to be  like this

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  Timer.startTimer(gon.timer);
});
```

After this I need to call `createTimer` from startTimer like this

```
 import Helpers from "../../global/helpers";
import TimerFunctions from "./timer_functions";
declare let gon: any;
export module Timer {
   export function startTimer (duration){
    let display: JQuery;
    display= $('#time_left');
    TimerFunctions.createTimer(duration,display,(() =>
    $.fancybox.open($('.session_timeout'), {
      afterClose() {
        return Helpers.navigate(gon.links.like_url);
      }
    })
    ))
   }
};

export default Timer;
```

And finally `createTimer` function in another file

```
    export namespace TimerFunctions {
  let session_timer;
  export function createTimer(duration, display, func) {
    Date.now = Date.now || (() => +new Date());
    const start = Date.now();
    let diff = 0;
    let minutes = 0;
    let seconds = 0;

    const timer = function() {
      diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
      let minutes: any = (diff / 60) | 0;
      let seconds: any = (diff % 60) | 0;
      if (minutes < 0) {
        minutes = "0";
      }
      if (seconds < 0) {
        seconds = "0";
      }
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;
      display.html(`${minutes}:${seconds}`);
      if (diff <= 0) {
        clearInterval(session_timer);
        return func();
      }
    };
    timer();
    return (session_timer = setInterval(timer, 1000));
  }
};

export default TimerFunctions;
```

Now all working perfectly.